# Wireless headset

Tags: headset, logitech

I've got a [Logitech ClearChat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015EY5RE) headset, and I love it, but I need something with better transmission strength. I've looked around for similar devices though and it seems as though the ClearChat is singular in its class. I'm having a very hard time doing detailed search though, as sales sites like Amazon & NewEgg don't have great search criteria for headsets.

I also found the [H20e](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-headset-dual-h820e-business), but sadly it's a "business-class" device and the response is a mushy 150Hz-7KHz. Useful only for person-to-person phone calls; unusable for music, games, or even group meetings.

Here are the things that I'm looking for:

- USB, not Bluetooth
- 20Hz-20KHz response (H20e can't do this)
- On-ear mute switch
- On-mic mute indicator LED
- Range greater than 10m (ClearChat can't do this)

Are there any headsets out there that satisfy these criteria?

Comment: Do you have a budget for this?

Comment: It's primarily a work device, so my budget is...generous, heh. I'll entertain any suggestion, regardless of price.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking around a bit, so far I've found the following two candidates, coincidentally all from SteelSeries (no, I am not affiliated, apparently they just *are* good):

- The [SteelSeries Siberia 840](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/siberia-840) can be used both wired (full quality, not using bluetooth) and wireless, has two battery packs for quick exchange and recharge, *and* additional bluetooth connectivity. Obviously that comes at a price around 300$. Actually there also is the [800](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/siberia-800) without bluetooth.
- The [Arctis 7](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/arctis-7) can be used wired and wireless, but it lacks bluetoth. The disadvantage is it only works via USB in wireless mode